# Check for existence of variable argument input

Tags: matlab

It takes variable number of arguments but how can i check if a particular variable argument exists like for example  `varargin{2}` , So far I have tried using `exist` but maybe I am not using it correctly

```
function vatest(testindex,varargin)

if (exist('varargin{1}','var'))
    disp('oneexist')
else if (exist('varargin{2}','var'))
     disp('twoexist')
    end
end
```

like for example `vatest(1,2,3)` should output

> twoexist

**NOTE:** I am already using `nargin` to get the number of inputs ,but please suggest something else than that

**UPDATE: Explanation for not using a nargin**

lets suppose I have a test function as above

```
function vatest(testindex,textindex2,textindex3,varargin)
```

and it does some something like

```
if nargin >3 
%%do something 
if nargin >4
%%do something 
if nargin >5 
%%do something 
if nargin >6 
%%do something 
if nargin >7 
%%do something 
if nargin >8 
%%do something
```

and for some reason I no longer need testindex3 in the input then I have to change condition for all the `if conditions`I hope it clarifies

Comment: I want to count only test varargin not the test index ~nargin~ already returns that

Comment: In your example, `vatest(1,2,3)` would output `oneexist`, because you check the first argument before you check the second.

Comment: Makes more sense now. But do you really want a the words? That's cumbersome and just unnecessary (IMO).

Comment: Actually I wanted a solution so that I don't have to change every condition , because I removed an input from a function which was unnecessary  and then had to change all the condition so needed a much simpler solution for the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`varargin` is simply a cell array containing the inputs. Therefore, you can determine how many inputs were provided by testing it's length: `numel(varargin)`.

`exist` is not really designed for this and is likely going to be much slower than simply determining the length of a known variable.

```
nInputs = numel(varargin)

if nInputs > 1
    disp('More than 1 input')
elseif nInputs > 0
    disp('Only 1 input')
else
    disp('No inputs')
end
```

Or more simply:

```
fprintf('%d inputs\n', numel(varargin));
```

Comment: Thanks you always amaze me with you simple solutions that sounds like a more convenient way using numel

Comment: @Umar, it looks like you are satisfied with Suever's answer. Please consider accepting it. It will make the question appear answered to anyone with a similar problem in the future, and it's a nice gesture to anyone answering your questions =)

Answer (score 1):

**YEY I finally got to use the `sexist` function:**

```
function vatest(testindex,varargin)

values = {'zero','one','two', 'three', 'four'};
fprintf('%sexist',values{numel(varargin)})
end
```

For some reason, you didn't want a space between "one" and "exist". So, this should do what you specified (but not necessarily what you want).

On a more serious note, I suggest `switch`:

```
function vatest(testindex, varargin)

num_argin = numel(varargin);
fprintf('%d inputs', num_argin);

switch num_argin
    case 1
        % Some code
    case 2
        % Some code
    case 3
        % Some code
    otherwise
        % Some code
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but with this solution i have to define a "so_good" array ! which is very inconvenient keeping in mind that varargin denotes a variable number of inputs and using "so_good" can result in exceeding cell index